# How to finish connection C# Postgres when I lose the network connection with the server

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql

I am having some problems to verify when the user is connected in the database or not because when the client lose the network the connection stay opened in the database so I want to finish those connections when the client lose the connection unexpectedly. Or a other way to verify the connection that are opened. I am using the query below;

```
Select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

Comment: Catch whatever Exception the broken connection causes and attempt a reconnect?

Comment: I don't have an exception the problem is that the connection continue in the server if I lose the network connection or energy connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a short [TCP keepalive interval](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-connection.html), so the server quickly notices when the client loses its connection.

There isn't really any other way to do it unless you somehow know via a sideband that a client connection is lost - in which case, as you noted, you can look it up in `pg_stat_activity` and `pg_terminate_backend(pid)` it.